# Stateless api with real time chat

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, mongodb, rest

So I have a REST api. I want to keep it stateless, but at the sametime I need to make a real time chat.

The only way I can imagine a real time chat, is with websockets. The problem accurs that websockets, to my knowledge, seems pretty statefull.

Is there another way to create a real time chat?

My stack is Spring boot (java)
React frontend
Mongodb for database.

Plan for hosting would be AWS

And normally I would just ignore the 100% stateless or statefull, but this is for a school project, and I would look good in my report, to say I am 100% stateless.

Answer (score 1):

the correct way achieving real time chats beside websockets would be to use firebase which is very common since usually the clients connected to your server will use android/iOS.

obviously an app connected to firebase is maintaining a stateful connection to firebase.

in general i dont think it is possible to provide push functionalities without state , as the server must reach the connected clients thus it must maintain those connections. if not using firebase, using websocket seems a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I might just make another api, which is statefull. Then I can talk about the differences between them!

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways of implementation this. Easiest - websockets. Hardest - backend is calling frontend.

More about second solution. In normal world, we are calling backend using frontend, here will be visa versa. When backend will receive a message (from another user), it will tell frontend that message was received ant it should show it.